# Laptop keyboard issue: all keys work but some are messed up like windows key alt key alt tab delete

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, regedit

My laptop is a Lenovo 330 and my windows key alt key and other do some wired codes like for example windows will do  Windows > qew-ruiop and dose alt > /gh can some one help

Comment: Sounds like you should get a trained technician to replace your keyboard

Comment: do you have the same behavior if using an external keyboard?

Comment: Nope if i use an external keyboard or use the on screen keyboard it works

Comment: unfortunately I will agree with @Ramhound you should get it to a certified technician

Comment: You might get by with just cleaning below the keys that can get stuck.

Comment: So there is nothing else cuz it worked before where it got fixed for a bit but i am not sure what i did

Comment: Sounds like who ever fixed it originally just juryriged it.